# ActionButton/ActionBar does not showup in TabHost method

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to have a different action bar for each new tab (activity) in my project

I have created my first Activity and put it as a tab  in my Main Activity

my first activity (tab) has the action button ( Start ) in the action bar of its activity

somehow nothing show up in the action bar for this tab
and if so I would to put more activities (tabs) no action bar/buttons will be shown

there is no error in my logcat

this is my code :

AndroidTabLayoutActivity.java

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for activity1
        TabSpec activity1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
        activity1.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, OneActivity.class);
        activity1.setContent(photosIntent);

        tabHost.addTab(activity1); // Adding photos tab
    }

}
```

OneActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class OneActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photos_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity1_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_start:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="b3du.im.tabLayout.AndroidTabLayoutActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

photos_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Screen Design for Activity1 -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="im the first one "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity1_actions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <!-- Exit -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_start"
        android:title="Start"
        android:showAsAction="withText|always" />


</menu>
```

Comment: no one can find a solution for this problem  ? hmmm

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the Action buttons in the main activity (where the tabs are hosted) NOT in the tab activiy.
And later manage them in the tab activity by using

```
 getParent().getActionBar()
```

and also..

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getParent().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_tabs, menu);
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_tabs, menu);
        return true;
    }
```